# Centering form elements in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have an interesting problem here.

I have two forms on the same page, the exact same code copy and pasted. Each form has a hidden input to identify the form on the backend, and each form has an `<input type="submit">` for submission.

The only difference between the two is that the first form has one less `<input type="text">`.

The problem is that the form with 3 `<input type="text">` fields is centered while the form with 2 `<input type="text">` is not. When I add a third `<input type="text">` the form is centered.

It seems as if the form has has to have a certain amount of inputs for it to center.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srx2U/1/)

Make sure to stretch your browser so you can see the whitespace on the right side of the top form.

And my HTML...

```
<div class="content-area">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                                    <div class="huge">Change Email</div>
                                    <form id="changeEmailForm" method="post" action="/resources/submit.php">
                                        <div class="input-group text-center">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="changeEmail"> <!-- Hidden input to identify the form -->
                                            <input class="form-control input-lg" id="newEmail" name="newEmail" minlength="2" type="text" required placeholder="New Email">
                                            <input class="form-control input-lg" id="confirmEmail" name="confirmEmail" minlength="2" type="text" required placeholder="Confirm Email">
                                            <input class="btn btn-large btn-success" type="submit">
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                                    <div class="huge">Change Password</div>
                                    <form id="changePasswordForm" method="post" action="/resources/submit.php">
                                        <div class="input-group text-center">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="changePassword"> <!-- Hidden input to identify the form -->
                                            <input class="form-control input-lg" id="currentPassword" name="currentPassword" minlength="2" type="text" required placeholder="Current Password">
                                            <input class="form-control input-lg" id="newPassword" name="newPassword" minlength="2" type="text" required placeholder="New Password">
                                            <input class="form-control input-lg" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" minlength="2" type="text" required placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                            <input class="btn btn-large btn-success" type="submit">
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NWmdA/)

Changing your text-center to `center-block` will center the element. I added it to the second because it wasn't a true center either.

```
<div class="content-area">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                            <div class="huge">Change Email</div>
                            <form id="changeEmailForm" method="post" action="/resources/submit.php">
                                <div class="input-group center-block">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="changeEmail">
                                    <!-- Hidden input to identify the form -->
                                    <!--<input class="form-control input-lg" id="newEmail" name="newEmail" minlength="2" type="text" required placeholder="New Email">-->
                                    <input class="form-control input-lg" id="newEmail" name="newEmail" minlength="2" type="text" required placeholder="New Email">
                                    <input class="form-control input-lg" id="confirmEmail" name="confirmEmail" minlength="2" type="text" required placeholder="Confirm Email">
                                    <input class="btn btn-large btn-success" type="submit">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                            <div class="huge">Change Password</div>
                            <form id="changePasswordForm" method="post" action="/resources/submit.php">
                                <div class="input-group center-block">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="changePassword">
                                    <!-- Hidden input to identify the form -->
                                    <input class="form-control input-lg" id="currentPassword" name="currentPassword" minlength="2" type="text" required placeholder="Current Password">
                                    <input class="form-control input-lg" id="newPassword" name="newPassword" minlength="2" type="text" required placeholder="New Password">
                                    <input class="form-control input-lg" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" minlength="2" type="text" required placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                    <input class="btn btn-large btn-success" type="submit">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, it doesn't work when I change that in my code. But I pasted my overriding CSS into JSFiddle and it works, but does not work inside my project, any thoughts there?

Comment: Nevermind, I just got a fresh copy of Bootstrap and it seems to be working, must be a problem that was fixed recently.